# sandbox paypal account transferring money to invalid accounts through php code

Tags: php, curl

In my api, I'm using PHP code to automatically transfer money amount from one sandbox **paypal** account to another sandbox **paypal** account.But through this PHP code, transactions are occurring for both valid as well as for invalid sandbox user accounts which must not not happen at all.

Furthermore, I cannot find any way to check in my code whether the receiver's sandbox account is valid or not. If it's valid, only then transfer money to the receiver's account.

Here is the code....

```
    //   Paypal_class.php 

    class Paypal {
     public function __construct($username, $password, $signature) {
    $this->username = urlencode($username);
    $this->password = urlencode($password);
    $this->signature = urlencode($signature);
    $this->version = urlencode("122.0");
    $this->api = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";

    //The functions can be modified but need to be urlencoded
    $this->type = urlencode("EmailAddress");
    $this->currency = urlencode("USD");
    $this->subject = urlencode("Instant Paypal Payment");
}

public function pay($email, $amount, $note="Instant Payment") {
    $string = "&EMAILSUBJECT=".$this->subject."&RECEIVERTYPE=".$this->type."&CURRENCYCODE=".$this->currency;

    $string .= "&L_EMAIL0=".urlencode($email)."&L_Amt0=".urlencode($amount)."&L_NOTE0=".urlencode($note);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $request = "METHOD=MassPay&VERSION=".$this->version."&PWD=".$this->password."&USER=".$this->username."&SIGNATURE=".$this->signature."$string";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("MassPay failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    $httpResponseArray = explode("&", $httpResponse);
    $httpParsedResponse = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseArray as $i => $value) {
        $tempArray = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tempArray) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponse[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponse)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponse)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($request) to ".$this->api);
    }

    return $httpParsedResponse;
}

}
?>
```

Here is the code where I am calling the above functions.....

```
   // pay.php  

  <?php

   require "Paypal_class.php";

    $paypal = new Paypal("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $send_payment = $paypal->pay("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "10.00", "Thanks for an amazing service");

   if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($send_payment["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($send_payment["ACK"]))
{
    exit('Pay Completed Successfully: '.print_r($send_payment, true));
} 
else 
{
    exit('Pay failed: ' . print_r($send_payment, true));
}
?>
```

The problem here is that whenever I hit this api, money transaction occurs even on putting in the wrong or invalid account id (sandbox).... Can anybody help me with the code ... i need a code  where i can check whether the receiver's account is valid or not.. if not then it shouldn't make any transactions...rather it must  return "Failure" message in response.

Please help